# What's the best way to go for a new type as alias of exisiting type (no type safety)?

Tags: c#, custom-type

Situation: I have variables like: `drift`, `heading`, `course`, `positionAbs` and `positionRel`. I could declare them all as `float` but I want to make it clear what "kind" they are, in different places in the code. That's why I thought about creating new types like `position` and `angle` as mere aliases for `float` and make the variables of the respective types.
I don't need type safe as I may combine them in trigonometric functions but it would be of great assistance to be aware of their "kind". C++ has `typedef` which would be perfect for my need but this is C#. 
The possible directions I've learned of are:

1. `using angle = System.Single` but this I have to include in each and every file I create. But I also have other code that I need in other files, so I created a namespace for both. I included the said line in the namespace but it's not taken into account, i.e. `angle` is not recognized.
2. Boxing `angle` and `position` in structs. This has the downside of writing a lot of code, maybe not even being able to write *all* the corresponding code.

   ```
   public struct angle  
   {   
       private float _val;   
       public angle(float val)   
       {
           _val = val;
       }

       public static implicit operator float(angle d)
       {
           return d._val;
       }

       public static implicit operator angle(float d)
       {
           return new angle(d);
       }
       //...
   }  
   public angle drift;  
   public angle course;
   ```
3. Adding "ang" or "pos" into the name of variables, like `driftAng`, `courseAng`, `positionAbsPos` etc. But this doesn't seem right.

Is there any other way? From the ones I know of I would personally prefer option 1 which, under the hood from what I can tell, is an automated option 2 anyway. What is the most professional approach in C# in this case?

Comment: Why not house them in an object that makes that clear, so that when you access `position.driftAng`, you know what it is: the drift angle at the current position. Rather than "retyping" it, "namespace" it.

Comment: Using descriptive names for your fields would seem the easiest-to-implement professional option.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: it's not position.drift, they're unrelated; all of them are on the same "level". All of them belong to a ship object.